# One executable with cmd-line params or just many satellite executables?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, architecture

I design an application back-end. For now, it is a .NET process (a Console Application) which hosts various communication frameworks such as Agatha and NServiceBus.

I need to periodically update my datastore with values (coming from the application while it's running).

I found three possible ways:

1. Accept command line arguments, so I can call my console app with -update.
2. On start up a background thread will periodically invoke the update method.
3. Create an updater.exe app which will do the updates, but I will have code duplication since in some way it will need to query the data from the source in order to save it to the datastore.

Which one is better?

Comment: Honestly, that is far too less information to give you a useful answer. All alternatives have it pros and cons, and what is best it depends heavily on a lot of different things, like execution environment, organisational environment, the existing architecture of your program, performance issues and so on.

Comment: Why do you have code duplication because you execute the same code from another executable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the simplest thing that will work. Sounds like option 1 is the way to go based on the info you have given.

Option 2 has threads, threads always complicate programs, more difficult to debug and write, greater chance of bugs.

Option 3, would mean that you have two apps, if you make a change you will have to deploy new versions of both, increasing maintenance costs.

Comment: Thanks, I chose the 1st option. That way I have no code duplication at all and I am re-using everything.